# new entity not detected

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I created a new entity in an entity folder where I already have some other used entity. However this new entity is not detected by doctrine:mapping:info nor doctrine:schema:validate

It appears the file is simply not taken into account (if I write an error inside symfony is executed without issue).

I was thinking about a VM system issue but then I tried to create other new files  (such as a new YML,a new symfony form) and it works...

I also cleared the cache:clear and doctrine:cache:all options

here is the class:

```
<?php


    namespace NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use JsonSerializable;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 */

    class test implements JsonSerializable
    {
        /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */

    protected $name;  

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */


    protected $description;



    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct($id = NULL)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = "Chart Of Accounts";
        $this->description = "Default chart of accounts";
    }


    //this method returns an array with default values
    public function getDefaultObject()
    {
        $result = Array();
        $result['id'] = $this->id;
        $result['name'] = $this->name;
        $result['description'] = $this->code;
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }


    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array(
            'id' =>  $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description
        );
    }

}
?>
```

where could this come from ?

Comment: You forgot the @ORM\Entity annotation ?

Comment: ahhh f.......... me seriously

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `@ORM\Entity` annotation for your class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 */

class test implements JsonSerializable
{
```